# Spotlight and Point Light not working in HDRP

Tags: unity, lighting, hdrp

I have a Unity project using HDRP, and in my scene only directional lights work.

Spot lights and point lights don't work, even if set them to a super high value.

How can I correct this?

Comment: What are the specific symptoms of "not working" that you're observing? What specific parameter have you set to a "super high value"? Can you walk us through the steps to create a Minimal Complete Verifiable Example, starting from a new, empty HDRP project?

Comment: hi boss, my simptoms for not working are that the surfaces of my meshes only react to directional light. I've set intensity of spotlight and point light to superhigh parameters and they don't impact on the scene.

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce this problem. Creating an HDRP project in Unity 2020.3.8f1 and adding spotlights and point lights into the sample scene shows them illuminating the scene geometry as expected. I did find I had to crank the intensity to get them to shine bright enough to be noticeable over the ambient lighting in the scene, but other than that they behaved as expected. Please **edit your question** to walk us through the steps needed to reproduce the problem that you're experiencing. Once we can reproduce it, we can test potential fixes to be sure they'll work for you.

Comment: I have the same problem at 2020.3.24f1. They worked in the beginning but now are just kinda broken. Did you get the reason of that?